# REST POST json body to support complex query advice

Tags: json, rest

I'm fairly new to REST.  All of our legacy webservices were SOAP based with enterprise (ORACLE or DB2) databases.   We are now moving to REST/couchbase.

Our team is looking into implementing a complex query method.   We already have implemented simple query methods using GET, for example GET returns all entries and a GET/067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00 would return the entry for 067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00.

We want to support a query method that would support receiving several query parameters such a list of Ids and date ranges.   The number of Ids can number into a few thousand and because of this, we realize we cannot pass these query parameters in a GET HTTP header since there is a limit on header size.

We are starting to look into passing our query parameters into the JSON body of a POST request.  For example, we could have client pass in a few thousand Ids as an array and also pass in a date range, so we'd have each query param/filter be an object.   The JSON body would then be an array of objects.  For example:

```
{
  "action" : "search",
   "queryParameters" : {
  [ 
   {
  “operation”: “in”,
  "key" : "name.of.attribute.Id",
  "value" : "[{ "id: "067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00"}, {"id": "next id"....}],
  },
 {
“operation”: “greater”,
  "key" : "name.of.attribute “,
   "value" :  "8/20/2016"
},
{
“operation”: “less”,
  "key" : "name.of.attribute “,
   "value" :  "8/31/2016"
  }
 ]
}
```

The back end code would then receive POST and read the body.   It would see action is a search and then look for any entries in the list that are in the list of Ids that are in the date range of > 8/20/2016 and < 8/31/2016.

I've been trying to look online for tips/best practices on how best to structure the JSON body for complex queries but have not found much.  So any tips, guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to query the json using java script manually or SQL/xpath type of query?

Comment: The actual query would be done in the backend thru java code.   We want a REST service to receive the search request and this will be coming from a java script client.   So we are trying to figure out a way for the client to pass what they want queried from the couchbase DB.  So this JSON is one thought to a request object that can be passed to the backend thru the REST call, the server would then perform the query and return a JSON array of objects.   I have been trying to find any tips online for how to construct POST queries to get around the HTTP header limit size, but have not found much

Comment: I will read links that say POST can be used to get around HTTP header size.  But that is it....no examples or direction on how to proceed.   I've read a few links stating POST can create a query resource and then call GET on that resource to retrieve data.  I've read other links that say POST is creating a query so server can return data.  But what I'd like to know is if there is a recommended structure to pass the request query.   It seems it depends somewhat on the parsing implemented by the server side, but I'd want more experience develops to offer tips.